# java print job cutting off the edge of the page

Tags: java, printing, jeditorpane

An application uses a jEditorPane to display html pages, which also has the ability to print said html page. We construct the MediaPrintableArea for the printerJob attributeSet like so:

```
    float mediaWidth = mediaSize.getX(Size2DSyntax.MM);
    float mediaHeight = mediaSize.getY(Size2DSyntax.MM);
    float imageableX = 18;
    float imageableY = 25;
    float imageableWidth = (mediaWidth - (2 * imageableX));
    float imageableHeight = (mediaHeight - (2 * imageableY));
    MediaPrintableArea imageableArea = new MediaPrintableArea(imageableX, imageableY, imageableWidth, imageableHeight, Size2DSyntax.MM);
```

So we control the printable area of the page. However, when the moons align and a single line is just the right length, the end of the last character in the line is being cut off.

EX: if a line ends with the word "to", there will only be the left-most half of the 'o' visible on the printed page. I would expect if this were to run off the edge of the printable are, "to" would wrap to the next line, but its not.

Is there some other method of defining the printable area besides using the MediaPrintableArea? Is there anything that can be causing the words to not wrap or how java calculates the placement of the words?

We've also tested several other printers and printed from browsers where we can print beyond there our java print job is cutting off, so I don't think hardware problems should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably rendering the JEditorPane starting from (0, 0) instead of from PageFormat.getImageableX(), PageFormat.getImageableY(). See http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/advprint.html for more information.